# Is there a way configure nano to do not ask for file name when executing command write out?

Tags: linux, nano

When I would like to save the edited file in nano, pressing ctrl + o, nano asks for the file name. I do understand, that it is necessary in case when the file has no name yet, and I do understand it allows me to save the file in an alternative name.

However in the majority of my cases the file already has a name, and I would like to save the file with exactly that name, so after pressing ctrl + o I always have to press the extra enter.

**Question**

Is there a way configure nano to do not ask for file name when executing command write out?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just press
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>
to save it under the same name.

Comment: Yes, I know. The question is, is there any way to save it using one keypress, ctrl+o. I am not only asking this just  because of the spare of the one extra keypress (but that would be 50%), but also the chance of accidentally one ore more extra keys between the ctrl+s and enter, which will cause the corruprion of file name. So in practice I do not just press ctrl+o, enter in a sequence, instead have to move my eye to the filename down, and confirm it is still the required, which is countable extra time.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way configure nano to do not ask for file name when executing command write out?

With the default keybindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does exactly that.